# adding a new object to a object of arrays using just array, and without creating a new array

Tags: java

as title i am looking to add a object to a array of objects, without creating a new array, and just using array as i have a max capacity i would like to keep to, and the array starts empty,

say the method and the code i currently have right now is

```
// constructor
Object[] object = new Object[500];
```

```
/addmethod
public void addObject(Object object)
{
array[index] = object;
index++;
}
```

i think as a basis this would work
but i keep returning null with this here, as the array[index] = object;

so i am unsure as to what is going on here

adding on to newer updated method ive been working on which also returns null at that stage

```
 int i = 0;
        object[i] = object;
        if (i < 500)
        {
            int number = 0;
            number++;
            object[i].setNumber(number);
            i++;
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

each object added has a identfication number variable set once added, outside of the inde and that extra number variable is what i added to indent starting with the first object as 1 and then 2,3,4, and so on

Comment: You know, `ArrayLists` do this for you.  They are backed by arrays and automatically increase capacity if required.

Comment: @WJS I believe this is an exercise to implement one.

Answer (score 0):

```
// constructor
Object[] objects = new Object[500];

/addmethod
public void addObject(Object object)
{
    objects[index] = object;
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't want to declare objects in the constructor.  Initialization, perhaps.  But not declaration.  It's a visibility/shadowing issue.